# Does the "Anihilaarg" really exist?

Tags: ben-10

In Ben 10 Omniverse we come up across a weapon called the "Anihilaarg"

Does it even exist or just a rumour?

Comment: Googling for "anaaialarg" literally returns only this page. If it was actually thing in a popular current TV show, surely someone would have mentioned it somewhere. Does this thing exist?

Comment: where do you come across it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Ben 10 Wikia](http://ben10.wikia.com/wiki/Anihilaarg) the Anihilaarg (presumably a contraction of the words "annihilate" and "aargh") is a **real** doomsday weapon which is seen in [one episode](http://ben10.wikia.com/wiki/So_Long,_And_Thanks_For_All_The_Smoothies) and referenced in [another](http://ben10.wikia.com/wiki/Mud_is_Thicker_than_Water).

[image: Anihilaarg]

Per the wikia page;

> The Anihilaarg first appeared in So Long, And Thanks For All The
>   Smoothies, where the vessel materialized in the universe and appeared
>   above the Earth, Argit was sent aboard the ship by Milleous to obtain
>   the Anihilaarg while the Vreedles sought it for themselves.
>
> Later in the episode, it was accidentally activated when Ben, Rook,
>   the Incurseans and the Vreedle Brothers were fighting to obtain it. It
>   destroyed the entire universe, but Ben recreated it as Alien X. With
>   the Anihilaarg activated, it's purpose of destroying a universe was
>   complete and was rendered useless as a weapon.
>
> Everyone present believed that the Anihilaarg was defective, unknowing
>   that the universe was even destroyed in the first place as Rhomboid
>   went over and crushed the Anihilaarg underfoot, destroying it
>   completely.
>
> In Mud is Thicker than Water, it's revealed that Blukic and Driba
>   fixed the Anihilaarg and that it's being kept at Plumber Headquaters
>   with a fake being used as bait.